# Syntax of pre-head noun complements to nouns

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, linguistics

In these kinds of NPs:

1. *a **flower** seller*
2. *an **income tax** advisor*

(from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 2002)

Are the emphasised nominal complements meant to be raw `N`s sibling to the head `N` in the tree? (As opposed to `N'`s or `NP`s?)

```
    NP
    /\
   /  \
Spec   N'
 |     /\
 a    N  N
     /    \
   flower  seller
```

How is the head of the NP (*seller* for (1) and *advisor* for (2)) told apart in the syntax tree from its complement?

Is this tree actually correct, and it's disambiguated by the (apparent) rule that only adjectives and nouns can be pre-head complements, and only PPs and clauses can be post-head complements?

The research I've done is reading the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149033/discussion-on-question-by-theonlygusti-syntax-of-pre-head-noun-complements-to-no); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Aren't such questions better suited to linguistics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Questions about English grammar belong here. This seems specific to English, it's not language-independent.

Answer (score 0):

The complements are certainly not NP's, since they can't take determiners; "the those flowers seller" is obviously incorrect. But they aren't necessarily bare nouns either, since they can take modifiers of other kinds, as in "an explosive gas detector" or "a criminal law expert" (as in "an expert on criminal law"). So it would be best to describe these as `N'`s, or, in Huddleston & Pullum's terminology, nominals, though here of course they consist only of a noun.

Comment: _*a flower big seller_ is not correct though? What do you mean that they can take modifiers?

Comment: Are you saying the correct structure is (NP a (N' (N' (N flower)) (N' (N seller))))

Comment: @theonlygusti Yes. "A flower big seller" is wrong only because of the constraints on the order of a noun's pre-head dependents (compare the rules for adjective order).